# Код для переключения картинками, jQuery

Tags: jquery

Написал а работает не корректно, нажимая на кнопки не все картинки переключаются, что тут не так ?

```js
$('.box').on('click', '.btn', (e) => {
  const srcAttr = $(e.target).data('src');
  $('.image').css('background-image', `url(${srcAttr})`);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* .Fon {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.logo {
     position: absolute;
}

.logo img {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 20vh;
    margin-top: 10vh;
} */

#slider {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slides article {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slides .image {
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}

#overflow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
}

#desktop:checked~#slider {
  max-width: 960px;
}

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
  background: url(../img/prev.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -84px;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background: url(../img/next.png) no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 -84px 0 0;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

label,
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.all input {
  display: none;
}

#switch1:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switch2:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#switch3:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#switch4:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#switch5:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

#controls {
  margin: -25% 0 0 0;
  margin-top: -174px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#active label {
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#active {
  margin: 16% 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#active label:hover {
  background: #76c8ff;
  border-color: #777 !important;
}

#switch1:checked~#active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked~#active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked~#active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked~#active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked~#active label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #18a3dd;
  border-color: #18a3dd !important;
}

#slides .image {
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}


/* #controls label:hover{ 
    opacity: 0.6;
} */

#controls label {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

.films {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex; */
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px;
}

.films span {
  font-size: 30px;
  /* margin-left: 20px; */
}

.films .p_1 {
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.films .p_2 {
  margin-left: 150px;
}


/* .films img {
    margin-top: 160px;
    height: 350px;
} */


/* .box1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  } */


/* button {
    font-size: 24px;
  } */

.image-box {
  /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center; */
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* //////// */


/* .box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  } */


/* button {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  
  .on {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .off {
    display: none;
  } */


/* ///////// */

.films .f_4,
.films .f_3,
.films .f_2,
.films .f_1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  /* border: 2px solid; */
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.films .f_4 li,
.films .f_3 li,
.films .f_2 li,
.films .f_1 li {
  list-style: none;
  /* font-size: 20px; */
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.films .f_4 li button .btn,
.films .f_3 li button .btn,
.films .f_2 li button .btn,
.films .f_1 li button .btn {
  /* list-style: none; */
  /* font-size: 20px; */
  width: 336px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  /* margin-top: 5px; */
  /* cursor: pointer; */
}

.films .f_4 li button p,
.films .f_3 li button p,
.films .f_2 li button p,
.films .f_1 li button p {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /*    width: 336px; */
}

.films .f_4 ul,
.films .f_3 ul,
.films .f_2 ul,
.films .f_1 ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.films .p_1 .f_4 li button,
.films .p_1 .f_3 li button,
.films .p_2 .f_2 li button,
.films .p_2 .f_1 li button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 365px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="Fon"> <img style="width: 100%;" src="img/Fon.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  <!-- <div class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt=""> </div>  -->

  <div class="all">
    <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
    <article id="slider">
      <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch5">
      <div id="slides">
        <div id="overflow">
          <div class="image">
            <article><img src="img/sl_1.jpg"></article>
            <article><img src="img/sl_2.jpg"></article>
            <article><img src="img/sl_3.jpg"></article>
            <article><img src="img/sl_4.jpg"></article>
            <article><img src="img/sl_5.jpg"></article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="controls">
        <label for="switch1"></label>
        <label for="switch2"></label>
        <label for="switch3"></label>
        <label for="switch4"></label>
        <label for="switch5"></label>
      </div>
      <div id="active">
        <label for="switch1"></label>
        <label for="switch2"></label>
        <label for="switch3"></label>
        <label for="switch4"></label>
        <label for="switch5"></label>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="films">
      <div class="p_1">
        <div class="f_4">
          <span> last film's </span>
          <ul>
            <div class="box">
              <li> <button data-src="img/posters/sec_war.jpg" class="btn"><p>Avengers: Secret War</p> </button> </li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/kang.jpg' class="btn"><p>Avengers: The Kang</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/four.jpg' class="btn"><p>Fantastic Four</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/dead.jpg' class="btn"><p>Untitled Deadpool Movie</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/blade.jpg' class="btn"><p>Blade</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/thunder.jpg' class="btn"><p>Thunderbolts</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/america.jpg' class="btn"><p>Captain America</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/marvel.jpg' class="btn"><p>The Marvels</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src="img/posters/galaxy.jpg" class="btn"><p>Guardians</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ant.jpg' class="btn"><p>Ant-Man</p></button></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="f_3">
          <span> last film's </span>
          <ul>
            <div class="box">
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/black.jpg' class="btn"><p>Black Panther 2 </p> </button> </li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/thor.jpg' class="btn"><p>Thor: Love </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/strange.jpg' class="btn"><p>Doctor Strange 2</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/spider.jpg' class="btn"><p>Spider-Man: No Way </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/eternals.jpg' class="btn"><p>Eternals </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/shang.jpg' class="btn"><p>Shang-Chihe Legend</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/widow.jpg' class="btn"><p>Black Widow </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/spider_2.jpg' class="btn"><p>Spider-Man 2 </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/endgame.jpg' class="btn"><p>Avengers: Endgame </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/captain.jpg' class="btn"><p>Captain Marvel </p> </button></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="image-box">
        <div class="image">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="p_2">
        <div class="f_2">
          <span> last film's </span>
          <ul>
            <div class="box">
              <li> <button data-src="img/posters/ant_2.jpg" class="btn"><p>Ant-Man 2</p></button> </li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/infinity.jpg' class="btn"><p>Avengers Infinit</p></button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/spider_1.jpg' class="btn"><p>Spider-Man: Homecoming </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/galaxy_2.jpg' class="btn"><p>Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/strange_1.jpg' class="btn"><p>Doctor Strange </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/captain_1.jpg' class="btn"><p>Captain America: Civil War </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ant_1.jpg' class="btn"><p>Ant-Man</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ultron.jpg' class="btn"><p>Avengers: Ultron </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src="img/posters/galaxy_1.jpg" class="btn"><p>Guardians of the Galaxy </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/america_1.jpg' class="btn"><p>Captain America: The Winter Soldier</p> </button></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="f_1">
          <span> last film's </span>
          <ul>
            <div class="box">
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/thor_1.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Thor</p> </button> </li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ironman_3.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Iron Man 3 </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/aveng.jpg' class="btn"> <p> The Avengers</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/america_2.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Captain America</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/thor_3.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Thor </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ironman_2.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Iron Man 2</p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/hulk.jpg' class="btn"> <p> The Incredible Hulk </p> </button></li>
              <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ironman.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Iron Man </p> </button></li>
              <!-- <li> <button data-src='img/posters/endgame.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Avengers: Endgame </p> </button></li>
        <li> <button data-src='img/posters/captain.jpg' class="btn"> <p> Captain Marvel </p> </button></li> -->
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>






      <!-- <div class="p_2"> 
    <div class="f_2"> </div> 

    <div class="f_1"> </div> 
     </div> -->

    </div>
  </center>





  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lab.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `const srcAttr = $(e.target).data('src') || $(e.target.closest('.btn')).data('src');` внутри button есть `<p>...</p>` по которому кликаете и у которого нет дата-атрибута со ссылкой

Comment: Ааа, это значит в html коде, в <p> . . . </p>, добавить class, то есть получаем вот это. <li> <button data-src='img/posters/ant.jpg' class="btn"><p data-src='img/posters/ant.jpg'>Ant-Man</p></button></li>

Comment: Проще убрать вообще <p>, он там не нужен, стилями то же сделать можно с :before или :after, к примеру.